# Can I use "therefore", "so", "hence" and "thus" interchangeably?

Tags: conjunctions, formality

I was taught that, at least, '*therefore*' and '*so*' and can be used interchangeably, one being informal, the other formal. But, even when written, replacing '*so*' with '*therefore*' doesn't seem correct.

> I was tired so I fell asleep.

...

> I was tired therefore I fell asleep.

Am I even allowed to use *therefore* as a conjunction here? The dictionary says I can, but it would seem more suitable to say:

> I was tired **and** therefore I fell asleep.

I realise *hence* and *thus* (and even *ergo*) are rarely used, but where do they fit into this?

Comment: "Therefore" is used in argumentation rather than trivial or descriptive contexts. If you are trying to convince someone with arguments, you would use "therefore"; in the sleep example, "so" fits better. Note that there should at least be a comma before "therefore".

Comment: You may wish to correct the spelling of the word "interchangeably" in your title.

Comment: Actually, in the sleep example, I would skip the "therefore" entirely and just use "and". But then maybe I'm just tired...

Comment: You can use the word "ergo"

Comment: As the answerers say, these words are certainly used interchangeably in many contexts.  However, there are subtle shadings in their original meanings.  "Therefore" started out as "therefor" and means something like "for this [reason]".  "Thus" and "so" mean "in this manner".  "Hence" means "from here".

Comment: This question is partially answered is a nice way here: [What's the difference between “hence” and “thus”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5355/386660)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Therefore* is an adverb, as well as *hence* and *thus*, although used in this similar manner they are conjunctive because they denote causal relation between the two clauses in your statement.

Both of your examples above are acceptable, but there should be a semicolon in your first *therefore* example:

> I was tired; therefore, I fell asleep.

Comment: Semicolons are important; they serve as appropriate punctuation between two related independent clauses.

Comment: And what's your excuse for the comma???

Comment: After 'therefore'? Because 'therefore' by itself isn't a clause?

Comment: So what's your excuse for the comma????

Comment: After 'therefore'? Because 'therefore' by itself isn't a clause?

Comment: "Use commas after introductory words" https://www.rd.com/culture/comma-rules/

Answer (score 23):

*Hence* and *thus* are by common usage interchangeable, however according to the rules of grammar they are different.

- *Hence* should indicate future use, such as "Hence we will do what we said."
- *Thus* should indicate the past or indicate a conclusion, such as "They couldn't see eye to eye, thus they didn't decide anything."

Comment: Sounds very scholarly. But have you authoritative support for these bold claims? (Oh, and Huddleston & Pullum say that the use of a comma before 'thus' at the start of a main clause is considered unacceptable.)