# Which one is less formal: hence, therefore, or thus?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the three is less formal, say, to be used in common speech?

Example:

> Cats have a parasite, Toxoplasma gondii. It's harmless to them—but in
>   humans it can affect the heart, liver, eyes. Also the mind. [...] its
>   correlation with suicide."

Comment: People tend to use *therefore* much more often than *thus* and way more often than *hence*.  But your statements don't lead me to your conclusion.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/can-i-use-therefore-so-hence-and-thus-interchangeably

Comment: See page 23 http://www.academia.edu/6888756/DISCOURSE_MARKERS_CONNECTORS_A_LIST_OF_DISCOURSE_MARKERS_WITH_EXAMPLES

Comment: I am forced to rephrase your entire phrase!

Comment: *"—but in humans it can affect the heart, liver, eyes* **and** *mind. As a result, it is correlated with suicide"*

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Suicide only refers to the mind part. That's why I put it apart from the rest.

Comment: I see what you mean, but leaving *mind* at the end of the list, the reader should reach the same conclusion. Although I suppose my sentence implies that the disease affects all these organs simultaneously, when in reality it does not. Hayes suggestion to write "as well as the mind" would fit better.

Comment: The parasite can cause encephalitis, neurological diseases, and can affect the heart, liver, inner ears and eyes. [Numerous studies found a positive correlation between latent toxoplasmosis and suicidal behavior in humans.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxoplasmosis) *...and also the mind. Therefore it's been connected with suicide*

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was about the scale of formality. Of these words I think it goes
1) therefore, 2) thus, 3) hence (from informal to formal).

Hence is often used incorrectly so I would try to avoid it, if at all possible.

You say you are looking for an acceptable informal word, although your example is not something that sounds like "common speech" to me. Perhaps you are making a presentation? I would rearrange it a little bit to avoid the problem.

> Cats have a parasite, Toxoplasma gondii. It's harmless to them—but in humans
>   it can affect the heart, liver, eyes, and also* the mind, which is why it has a correlation with with suicide.

- or: as well as the mind.
  I don't like also at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: I also would suggest "Cats **can** have a parasite..." unless all cats have it from birth.

Comment: @Jim Well spotted! It's so easy to concentrate only on one part of the phrase and miss the obvious.

Comment: I missed that too!

Answer (score 1):

In my (non-native speaker's) opinion you can only use ***hence*** in your specific example.

The other two would need more elaboration in ascending order of being seen as fact.

- *hence its correlation with suicide.* - works
- *therefore/so it may be/is correlated with suicide.* - works
- *thus it is correlated with suicide.* - works

but have subtle differences in meanings

The correlation is a possibility. This comes across in *hence its correlation*. *Thus its correlation* does not work for me. Neither does *therefore its correlation* nor *so its correlation* which all sound non-grammatical to me.

Comment: In the last two constructions, one could use the even-less-formal "so".

Comment: Still an even more subtle difference in my opinion @BrianHitchcock - the user of correlation points to a possibility which is shown by "hence" but less so by "thus" and the least by "so"