# What is the difference between therefore and hence?

Tags: compound-adjectives

In the following two sentences, what is more appropriate and why - hence or therefore?

> I Missed the bus hence I had to take a cab
>
> I Missed the bus therefore I had to take a cab

Or they can be replaced for each another?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/can-i-use-therefore-so-hence-and-thus-interchangeably

Comment: Not only related, but for all practical purposes an actual duplicate. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

"hence" is rarely used these days, especially in conversation and especially when talking about buses!

It originally meant 'from here'. If you are aware of that fact, then your sentence, "I missed the bus hence I had to take a cab." takes on an ambiguity. It could mean:

*I missed the bus.  Hence I had to take a cab.*  ---> "Therefore I had to ..."

or it could be

*I missed the bus hence. I had to take a cab.* ---> "I missed the bus from here...